# Calling PHP to send an email through Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have an HTML webpage, and am trying to use Javascript to call a separate PHP page to send an email. I know this is a bit of an unnecessary step in most cases, but I am using a Java framework that does not support PHP files, so I need to work around that. I am using JQuery to access the PHP, but whenever I try to send an email, I get an error from PHP saying `[object Object] error Not found`. Any suggestions or ideas?

Here is my HTML:

```
     <form name="feedback-form" id="feedback-form" class="w3-center">
        <h4 class="w3-center" style="max-width:1000px;align-content:center;"><label>Your email address</label></h4>
        <input id="email" style="max-width:300px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto" class="w3-center w3-input w3-border" name="email" placeholder="name@website.com" required>          
        <h4 class="w3-center" style="max-width:1000px;"><label>Feedback</label></h4>
        <textArea id="message" cols="10" rows="5" class="w3-center w3-input w3-border" name="message"></textArea>
        <h4 class="w3-center" style="max-width:1000px;" id="ifSuccess"></h4>
        <h4><button style="max-width:250px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round w3-hover-light-grey w3-center" onclick="sendMail()" type ="button" name="submit" id="submit">Enter</button></h4>
     </form>
```

Here is my Javascript function sendMail():

```
<script>
function sendMail() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "email.php", 
        data: {email: $("#email").val(),
            message: $("#message").val()},
        success: function () {$("#ifSuccess").html("Message sent successfully!");},
        error: function (req, status, error) {alert(req + " " + status + " " + error);}
        }); 
};
</script>
```

And - in a separate file called email.php, here is my PHP:

```
<?php 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $text = $_POST['message'];
    $to = "recipient@gmail.com";
    $from = $email;
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Form submission copy";
    $message = "You have received the following feedback email:" . "\n\n" . $text;
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . "\n\n" . $text;
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2);
?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the error is from your code, you specifically set the format in that alert. req is an object, status is a string with error and error is a string with not found. Its telling you that `email.php` is not found, check its actually there, you may need  slash in front if your in sub dir etc. Also your email code is open to header injection and spamming.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone both the .html file (with the Javascript) and the .php are in the same folder, src/main/resources. I just tried the same code with ```/email.php``` and still didn't work.

Comment: Incorrect `<textArea></textArea>`. Correct tag name is `<textarea></textarea>`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because Ajax doesn't pass the values normally. And the tag name is also wrong.

So try this.

**HTML**

```
<form id="feedback-form" class="w3-center" name="feedback-form">
   <h4 class="w3-center" style="max-width: 1000px; align-content: center;">
     <label>Your email address</label>
   </h4>
   <input id="email" class="w3-center w3-input w3-border" name="email" placeholder="name@website.com" style="max-width: 300px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" required/>
   <h4 class="w3-center" style="max-width: 1000px; align-content: center;">
     <label>Feedback</label>
   </h4>
   <textarea id="message" class="w3-center w3-input w3-border" name="message" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea>
   <h4 id="ifSuccess" class="w3-center" style="max-width: 1000px; align-content: center;"></h4>
   <h4>
     <button id="submit" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round w3-hover-light-grey w3-center" onclick="sendMail()" type="button" name="submit" style="max-width: 250px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        Enter
     </button>
   </h4>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
   function sendMail() {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "./email.php",
          data: $("#feedback-form").serialize(),
          success: function () {
             $("#ifSuccess").html("Message sent successfully!");
          },
          error: function (req, status, error) {
             alert(req + " " + status + " " + error);
          }
      });
   }
</script>
```

I assumed you were using your PHP code exactly as you originally wrote it.